# php image file is not copying in the folder

Tags: php

This is error showing page.i cant find any clues why showing these errors. The image file is not copying the images folder.

> Notice: Undefined index: image in C:\xampp\htdocs\Project\Manpower.php on line 36
>   Notice: Undefined index: image in C:\xampp\htdocs\Project\Manpower.php on line 38
>   Warning: copy(): Filename cannot be empty in C:\xampp\htdocs\Project\Manpower.php on line 38

```
        <?php
        include_once'db_connect.php';
        session_start();


        $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "travelagent");

        if(isset($_POST['status']))
        {

          if (!isset($_SESSION["username"]))

          {    

           $message = "please login!!";
           echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$message');</script>";



         }

         else

         {    
          $id = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['id']);
          $username=$_SESSION["username"];


          $_SESSION['id']=$id;
          $sql = "UPDATE product SET status='1' WHERE id='$id' " ;

          if(mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql)==true)

          {

         $image_path= mysqli_real_escape_string( $mysqli ,'images/'.$_FILES['image']['name']);       

         if(copy($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'],$image_path))

         {


            $_SESSION['image']=$image_path;


            $image=$_SESSION['image'];

           $sql="INSERT INTO cart (user_name, product_id,image) VALUES ('$username','$id','$image')";

           $result=$mysqli->query($sql);

           $message = "added to cart!! ";

           echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$message');</script>";



           session_destroy();
             }
         }


       }
     }

     ?>

     <!DOCTYPE html>
     <html lang="en">
     <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>Polyworld Services</title>
      <meta name="Description" content="Polyworld">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width:device-width" initial-scale="1">
      <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

      <!-- Optional theme -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">


      <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

      <script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"
      integrity="sha256-iT6Q9iMJYuQiMWNd9lDyBUStIq/8PuOW33aOqmvFpqI="
      crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

      <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">


      <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

      <!-- Custom CSS -->
      <link href="css/full-slider.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">


    </head>

    <body  data-spy="scroll" data-target="#my-navbar">

      <?php 

      include'header.php';

      ?>



      <h1 style="text-align:center;">Welcome to Manpower page</h1> 

      <div class="row" id="content">
        <?php 

        $result=$mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM product WHERE category_id='1' AND sub_category_id='1' AND status='0'" );

        while($row=$result->fetch_array())

        {                 
         ?>


         <div class="col-md-3">

          <ul> 










            <li>picture : <?php    echo "<img src='admin/".$row['image']. "' height='200' width='200'>";  ?> </li>
            <li>Name: <?php  echo $row['name'];           ?></li>

            <li>Description :<?php    echo $row['description'];        ?></li>
            <li ><a href="#">Details</a></li>
            <form action="" method="post">
              <input type="text" name="id" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">
              <input type="hidden" name="image" value="<?php echo $row['image']; ?>">  




              <li><input type="submit" name="status" value="add to cart"></li></br>
            </form> 
          </ul>


        </div>





        <?php                 

      }

      ?>
    </div>                 


    <?php  include'footer.php'; ?>

    <script type="text/javascript">


    </script>


    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/custom.js">

    </script>

    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>




    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: Why are you using `$_FILES` when your form doesn't contain any file upload? Your `image` is simply a hidden input field and should be accessed with `$_POST['image']`.

Comment: `<form action="" method="post" enctype='multipart/form-data' >`  just do this, nothing to change except this

Comment: @ParagSoni No, that doesn't change _anything_ in this case, since the field the OP is trying to access _is just a hidden input filed_, and _not_ a `file`-input.

Comment: @tadman how can i do that?

Comment: My comment is full of links that explain.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson thanks man you solves it

Comment: While its fine that your problem is solved, there are many other problems with your code. `session_start` not at the beginning... You include a db_connect but 2 lines after you create a connection? No prepared statements... This script is written really bad. If you want, we can go trough and fix it... but as I know SO users, they're often not really interested in improving their script, as long as they work...

Answer (score 0):

Try this code to upload file

```
$dir="image/";//name of the folder where the file need to be copied
$file=$dir . basename($_FILES["photo"]["name"]);// where 'photo' is the field name of file input
$filetype=pathinfo($file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["photo"]["tmp_name"], $file)) {
echo "upload success";
}
```